# iOS ARKit : Integrate AR feature in existing iOS Project

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I'm learning ARKit, wants to integrate in my existing iOS project.
I googled and got references for fresh projects only.

Any idea for old one?

Comment: Please clear your requirements, how you want to integrate ARKit in existing project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For integrating ARKit in your existing project.

1. Make sure your project is in Xcode 9 only.
2. Import ARKit in your existing project.
3. Create an Assets catalog and rename its extension to .scnassets.
4. Add your 3D models in this folder.

Your setup is done.

**NOTE** - Your existing project now will only be limited for iOS 11 and devices with A9 or later processor.

Comment: Just a side note regarding the limitation to iOS 11. I've faced this, with an app that still had to support iOS 10 and older devices, ARKit was just an add-on feature for newer devices. You can check the `isSupported` flag and use @available(iOS 11.0, *) -or #if available(iOS 11.0, *)- where needed. Be sure not to add `arkit` to `UIDeviceRequiredCapabilities`in the plist if you follow this approach.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arconfiguration/2923553-issupported